# How can a person sue oneself?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, california, india, justification

Either in USA California or in India (choose whichever you like) can a person sue oneself back for damages? Has anyone ever defamed themselves and then sued themselves for defamation?

Comment: Some examples can be found at https://loweringthebar.net/category/autolitigation

Comment: I have made this question not opinion based by making it historical. Either something has or hasn't occurred in the past (without regard to what may happen in the future).

Comment: Probable duplicate of [Has anyone ever won a lawsuit against oneself?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/1108/10)

Answer (score 4):

https://www.mwl-law.com/how-to-sue-yourself-and-win/

Yes, and there can be cases this is profitable.

1. You negligently killed someone in a car accident.
2. You need to sue yourself to use your insurance.
3. The victim is dead so their estate goes to you.
4. So you sue yourself on the estates behalf, the estate wins, and you get the estate.

Directly suing yourself is impossible however.

Comment: I read the linked article - and am still confused :)

Comment: Basically, if you inherit a estate you can be 2 people at once

Comment: This would not be suing yourself; it would be the estate suing you -- similar to Facebook suing Mark Zuckerberg.

Comment: Yes, correct. Otherwise is impossible.

Comment: @bdb484 All suits must be brought by and against recognized legal entities, and an estate is not a legal entity in this case/jurisdiction.  The executor of the estate is the legal entity.

Comment: Which jurisdiction are you talking about?

Comment: @bdb484 The case this answer provides a link to.

Comment: Utah? What makes you think an estate is not a legal entity in Utah? The IRS treats them as legal entities throughout the United States.

Comment: @bdb484 Utah is a different jurisdiction from the federal government for one.  And the IRS is not the judiciary and has different rules for two.  [Estates, in and of themselves, can't be sued in Florida, either](https://www.flprobatelitigation.com/2017/03/articles/new-probate-cases/practice-procedure/2d-dca-is-an-estate-a-legal-entity-that-can-be-sued/) and federal district courts have upheld the general principle that estates are not legal entities that can participate in litigation (see quotes and their references in prior link).  It is the representatives of estates who participate.

Comment: I see what you're saying. But even then, do you actually have anyone suing anyone? You just have people coming into an existing probate-court proceeding and asserting their position. And even when you actually sue the administrator, it's more like an official-capacity 1983 claim -- the person's name is on the case, but they aren't really responsible for defending and aren't going to be the one to pay any damages.

Comment: @bdb484 It's a bit of a legal fiction/technicality, yes.  As my prior link also indicates, courts have ruled that plaintiffs should be given a reasonable opportunity to fix their filings when they mistakenly try to sue an estate directly, rather than the representative.  But it's good to get it straight the first time around just to avoid the costs of having to appeal on a technical matter before the case even gets anywhere.  So on a colloquial, every-man level, yes, you're suing or being sued by the estate and we all know what you mean by that.  But on a technical legal level, you are not.

Comment: Conceptually, this answer is on the right track, but wrong in important details. (1) Wrongful death actions are generally vested in next of kin, rather than a probate estate, (2) insurance policies have provisions that partially address this possibility, (3) the person at fault would probably be disqualified by the court from being the person controlling the wrongful death action, and (4) this is really two people and not one it isn't truly suing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sue yourself, although sometimes related entities or parties can sue each other.